# Select query to select some tables which may not exist using join

Tags: mysql

This is where I have reached after trying my best

```
   select 13c_name,13c_mobile,13c_pid,p.13c_usid,p.13c_comp_id,13c_amount,
   13c_mode,13c_month,13c_year,13c_rec,13c_rec_date,13c_check,13c_comments,
   13c_status,13c_ip,13c_message,13c_rec_by,13c_invoice_pay from 
        
   13c_users u , 13c_payments p 
        
   where ( (u.13c_usid=p.13c_usid and 13c_subs='1') and (13c_year IN ('$new_year') and 13c_month NOT IN (1|2|3|4) or 13)  )
```

What I want to achieve is something like this

> I want to select all the members from `13c_users` who have subscribed
> `(13c_subs='1')` to monthly payments from table `13c_payments` who may not
> have paid any of the month of any year till now (`13c_month` stores the
> **month** number  and `13c_year stores` the **year** number in `13c_payment` table)

Now above query works some what nice but it does not select the users who have not paid anything yet, like of the user is subscribed and have not paid for any month the query will not match the join tbale with him.

Please check the query what I am doing wrong here!

////////////////////////////////// **EDITED** ///////////////////

This is until so far I could reach still I am not getting expected results:

```
select * from ( (select * from 13c_users u Left JOIN 13c_payments p ON
u.13c_usid=p.13c_usid where (13c_subs='1' and u.13c_comp_id='$yid') ) as T ) 
where ( (13c_year is NULL or 13c_year IN (2019) ) and (13c_month IS NULL or 
13c_month NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)) and (T.13c_invoice_pay='0' or T.13c_invoice_pay is 
NULL ))
```

The above query, selects all the members who have never paid but not those members who have paid for the first 2 months and not after that.

Table payment gets the entry of every payment made in separate rows.

I know there is something wrong in this part of query for sure

```
(13c_year is NULL or 13c_year IN (2019) ) and (13c_month IS NULL or 
 13c_month NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
```

I want to select the row if the row does not have any of the month as mentioned there 13c_month NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) but the rows are separate so it will always select every row

User table
[image]

Payments Table
[image]

Comment: please provide sample data and expected output

Comment: alias your column  with respect of your table. also you can use left join instead of inner join /cross join.

Comment: select T.* (select * from 13c_users u Left JOIN 13c_payments p ON u.13c_usid=p.13c_usid where (13c_subs='1') as T ) from  T -- Can you tell me what is wrong here ??

Comment: This Query is not working either ! 

    select * from (select * from 13c_users u Left JOIN 13c_payments p ON u.13c_usid=p.13c_usid where (13c_subs='1') as T ) T where (13c_month NOT IN (1|2|3|4|5))

Comment: What is (1|2|3|4) supposed to do?

Comment: @amani 
select T.* from (select * from 13c_users u Left JOIN 13c_payments p ON u.13c_usid=p.13c_usid where 13c_subs='1') as T 
 --compare this with above query select T.* (select * from 13c_users u Left JOIN 13c_payments p ON u.13c_usid=p.13c_usid where (13c_subs='1') as T ) you will find the error

Comment: It's not obvious when a user is supposed to start making payments,

Comment: @P.Salmon hello, can you see my update query in question and can help me ??

Comment: @Kandy  hello, can you see my update query in question and can help me ??

Comment: @Amani. Please provide sample data and required output so that we can analyze and provide you query as per requirement.

Comment: @amani you haven't answered the question how do you know when is a user is supposed to start making payments

Comment: @P.Salmon the user is supposed to pay every month any time. regarding starting date lets consider it from jan 2018

Comment: @Kandy what do you mean by sample data required output should i upload a screenshot of my database structure here ??

Answer (score 1):

Here's a much simplified example where I work out the number of expected payments and the number of months in which payment has been made - if not the same then I am interested

```
drop table if exists u,t;
create table u (id int,subs int, dt date);
create table t (uid int,dt date);
insert into u values (1,1,'2019-01-01'),(2,1,'2018-11-01'),(3,1,'2018-09-01');
insert into t values
(1,'2019-01-01'),
(2,'2018-11-11'),(2,'2018-11-13'),(2,'2019-01-01');



select id,
        ((year(now()) * 12 + month(Now())) -  (year(u.dt) * 12 + month(u.dt))) + 1 numexpected,
        coalesce(s.paidup,0) paidup
from u
left join
(select t.uid,count(distinct year(t.dt),month(t.dt)) paidup
from t
group by t.uid) s on s.uid = u.id
where ((year(now()) * 12 + month(Now())) -  (year(u.dt) * 12 + month(u.dt))) + 1 <> coalesce(s.paidup,0);

+------+-------------+--------+
| id   | numexpected | paidup |
+------+-------------+--------+
|    2 |           3 |      2 |
|    3 |           5 |      0 |
+------+-------------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note the expectation that a payment should be made every month seems a bit simplistic - what about pre-payments and late payments? For example UID 2 has made 3 payments but 2 were in the same month.